# Fill file input after form submit / on form submit error

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I´ve a multipart form with a mixture of default inputs (text, select etc.) and a file upload (`<input type="file">`).

I´m using a combination of form validation class and upload library of Codeigniter for form submission. That works great.

I´ve only one problem for what I haven´t found a solution yet: If the user selects an image but misses to fill another required field (like "name"), then the form validation class blocks the request and shows an error message to the customer.

But now I´ve the problem, that the image was already submitted successfully and I don´t want to let the user add the file again. So I want to pre-fill the file input with this data.

I´ve tried different things like:

```
<input type="file" name="image" value="<?php echo set_value('image','');?>" />
```

and also spent time on finding a solution on the web but without success.

Comment: Try to use a hidden input when user already uploaded the image like `<input type="hidden" name="image_already_up" value="<?php link of already up;?>" />` now after form submission again check user submitted file again if not then check the hidden input field.if it has value means he already uploaded it else user did not attach image yet.Hope you will get the idea.

Answer (score 7):

On the server side, you do not get any information about *where* the file is located on the client's computer, so in the scenario of a user uploading an image successfully but the user hasn't filled out the rest of the fields properly, you have to simply omit the `input type="file"` field entirely but keep a store of where the file is located on your server. There's a few ways to go about this, but it all involves taking the absolute location of the uploaded file and:

1. Inserting it back as a hidden value using `<input type="hidden" name="uploadedFile" value="<?php echo $absPath; ?>" />` then checking for the existence of `$_POST['uploadedFile']` and utilizing it appropriately. But this isn't a solid idea as you're now exposing server paths to the end-user (opens yourself up to malicious attack.)
2. Starting a session and saving the absolute path in the `$_SESSION` variable while presenting the user with a simple token in their re-attempt form.

I'd stick with method 2, so assuming you've done all the work to validate the form and upload the file and your file is located in `$absFilePath`, you could do the following:

```
session_start(); // This needs to be at the very top of you PHP file

// ...

$formToken = md5(time());
$_SESSION['uploadedFile'][$formToken] = $absFilePath;
```

Then render the token as a hidden variable using:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['uploadedFile'][$formToken]))
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="formToken" value="'.$formToken.'" />';
```

and hide the file upload portion using

```
if (empty($_SESSION['uploadedFile'][$formToken]))
    echo // <input type="file" output here...
```

finally inside of your form submission code check for the existence of a `formToken` value before attempting to load `$_FILES['image']` using `isset($_POST['formToken'])`, and handle it using:

```
$absFilePath = $_SESSION['uploadedFile'][$_POST['formToken']];
```

Bam! Now you have your absolute file path as if the file had been uploaded just like before.

Since you haven't given enough code, I can only given you enough instruction to get you started, but this should be more than enough.

Comment: Ok, so it seems there is no design pattern in CI which allows me to solve the problem!? A "manual" solution is always a way to go but not really nice when using a framework :) Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: @Michael Frameworks are frameworks... they provide you with barebone stuff and helper functions that make the work easier, but doesn't do it all! Even my favourite framework, Symfony, doesn't have a completely elegant way to handle file uploading since there's so many preferred ways to achieve it. Since you are using CI, you can replace the `$_POST` variables with the post helper functions that CI provides too. If you feel that this answer has helped you or solved your question, please feel free by marking it as correct :)

Comment: I know the sense of a framework :) But it would not be the first time that I´m building a complex functionality on my own to find out one week later, that this function is already provided by the framework but I didn´t find it (for what reason ever) :)