# I am trying to fetch the rows in my input fields using rowCount but image is getting failed

Tags: php, html, image

[Image is displaying all the fields with data coming from database but in the image field it is saying no file chosen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NavIU.png)I am trying to fetch the rows that has specific columns such as title ,slug and image. But i am getting failed to fetch the image for a specific id.
All fields are getting the data from database. But image is getting failed.
 The current code is following:-

```
enter code here
if (isset($_GET['piD'])) {
$piD = $_GET['piD'];
$fetch = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=?");
$fetch->execute(array($piD));
if ($fetch->rowCount()>0) {
$postRow = $fetch->fetch();
$title   = $postRow['title'];
$email   = $postRow['email'];
$slug    = $postRow['slug'];
$body    = $postRow['body'];
$image   =$postRow['image'];
}
else
{
header('location:posts.php?no post found');
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill file input after form submit / on form submit error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788308/fill-file-input-after-form-submit-on-form-submit-error)

Comment: Respected sir, what should be the value ? as i have value="<?php echo $image;?>" in my input field.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the file input value. To check the image value just `echo $image;` somewhere on your page.